# Read from LocalStorage

Tags: windows-phone-8

In the jumpstart videos (Building apps for Windows Phone 8 Jumpstart)
they showed sample code that gave me the error:
"The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task of T

This is the sample code:

```
//open
private async string loadStringAsync()
{
   string theData = string.Empty;

   //Get a reference to the local folder
   StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
   StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.store");

   //Open it and read it
   Stream readStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
   {
     theData = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
   }
   return theData;
}
```

I guess it needs a simple fix, but as I'm new to programming and the comments are disabled on that particular video, I don't know how..

Comment: Did you read the error?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think it might be best to read up on Asynchronous Programming first indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = loadStringAsync();

private async Task<string> loadStringAsync()
{
    string theData = string.Empty;

    //Get a reference to the local folder
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.store");

    //Open it and read it
    Stream readStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
    {
       theData = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    return theData;
}
```